# Cannot create file in databases folder

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, fileoutputstream, dot42

I am trying to copy a ready made sqlite v3 database from my assets folder into the /databases folder of my app. But I get a java runtime exception.

```
private const string DB_PATH = "/data/com.MyApp/databases/dbname";

        public SQLiteDatabase GetDataBase()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;

            try
            {
                db = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }
            catch
            {
                this.GetReadableDatabase();
                InputStream inStream = _appContext.GetAssets().Open("HadithCompanion.bukhari");
                Helper.CreateFileFromInputStream(inStream, new File(DB_PATH));
                db = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }

            return db;
        }


        public static void CreateFileFromInputStream(InputStream inStream, File destination)
        {
            try
            {
                OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destination); // THIS CAUSES THE FAILURE
                CopyFile(inStream, outStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.E("OutputStream", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The exception is not caught in the catch. The file "/data/com.MyApp/databases/dbname" does not yet exist, I assume by reading the docs that it would be created upon instantiating the FileOutputStream.

I am using C# and dot42 and testing on a real device using JellyBean 4.2